# Precedence of @DatabaseSetup and @BeforeTransaction Spring DBUnit and Spring Transaction

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, transactional, spring-test-dbunit

I have a JUnit test where I am using [Spring Test DBUnit](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/) and [Spring declarative transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained). If I tag a test method with @Transactional (which will utilize the @BeforeTransactional to verify database state) and also with @DatabaseSetup (to set the database state to what I want), which will have precedence? Will the database first be set up and then @BeforeTransactional will check it, or will the check happen after setup? Here's some code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = PersonServiceConfiguration.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
public class PersonServiceTransactionalIT {

    @Autowired
    private PersonManagementService pms;

    @BeforeTransaction
    public void beforeTransaction() {

        checkDatabaseState();
    }

    @AfterTransaction
    public void afterTransaction() {

        checkDatabaseState();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @DatabaseSetup("/test_data_start.xml")
    public void testCreateValid() {

        Person expected = new Person(6l, "six", "created");
        Person actual = pms.save(expected);
        assertEquals("Person objects not equal", expected, actual);
    }

    private void checkDatabaseState() {

        List<Person> pl = pms.findAll();
        assertEquals("Size of database not as expected", 5, pl.size());
    }
}
```